# Load NIB from variable

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, xib, nib

I'm trying to load a NIB based on a variable I get from my settings file. This is the code:

```
//select the right nib name
NSString *nibVar = [nibs objectForKey:@"controller"];

// create the view controller from the selected nib name
UIViewController *aController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibVar bundle:nil];
aController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:aController animated:YES];
[aController release];
```

This unfortunately does not work.

Any ideas here?

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the console shows you an error? Does happen nothing?

Comment: It gives out this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x4f3bad0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key scroller.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate "UIViewController" with arbitrary NIBs, you have to instantiate "[whatever your custom view controller class is]" with the NIB for that class.

It's crashing because it's trying to access properties that don't exist in UIViewController.

If you want to do this kind of dynamic view-controller loading, you need to do a bit more work, and use the special Class class method that lets you instantiate an object using a string for the class name, instead of hard-coded.

Sometehing like:

```
Class viewControllerClass = NSClassFromString( nibVar );
UIViewController* aController = (UIViewController*) [[viewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:nibVar bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Check. Good to know! Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the NIB name is correct and does not include the xib extension. It is also case sensitive.

Comment: The NIB is correctly named. If I paste the name from the plist into the code everything works like a charm!

Comment: Something goes wrong in the setting of UIViewController. If I replace these with my classname 'settingsViewController' and I leave the initWithNibName:nibVar untouched then it works.