# initWithNibName use partial nib name rather than full nib name

Tags: string, nsstring, xib, nib

So i want to initialise my view controller with a nib however i don't want to use the full name of the nib just the first four characters as the remaining characters vary.

As you can see below in my code all of my nibs follow a format the format is 1_somenumber_sometext. Somenumber is substituted with xibNumber, xibNumber is a number from 1 to 10 this is calculated seperately and just added into the nib name, no need to worry about it.

```
NSString* xibName =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"1_%@_sometext", xibNumber];

childController = [[CategoryOneDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil];
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If xibNumber is a number (NSInteger or int), replace that `%@` with `%i`. If it is a double or float, use `%d` or `%f`. `%@` is a token used to signify an object, so it won't work for primitive types like NSInteger or int.

Comment: xibNumber is an NSNumber, however you didn't answer my question.

Comment: If xibNumber is an NSNumber, then you define xibName to be [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"1_%i_sometext",[xibNumber intValue]]; Am I missing what the question is?

Comment: Yup, i want to initialise my view controller with a nib however i don't want to use the full name of the nib just the first four characters as the remaining characters vary.

Comment: Maybe this is what you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417889/load-nib-from-variable/5418747#5418747